# Postgres drop exclusion constraint

Tags: postgresql

I ran this DDL to add an exclusion constraint to a table:

```
ALTER TABLE recurring_charges
  ADD EXCLUDE USING GIST (period WITH &&);
```

Now I want to remove the constraint - how do I do that? I tried some variations of `ALTER TABLE ... DROP EXCLUDE` and `DROP CONSTRAINT` but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out - looks like it generated a name for the constraint that I have to use.

```
ALTER TABLE recurring_charges
  DROP CONSTRAINT recurring_charges_period_excl;
```

And now I've updated my original DDL to use the full `ADD CONSTRAINT` syntax so that I can name my constraint rather than relying on automatic naming behavior:

```
ALTER TABLE recurring_charges
  ADD CONSTRAINT recurring_charges_period_excl EXCLUDE USING GIST (period WITH &&);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answer, to find out the constraint name, you can find it in psql using:

`\d+ tableName`